# How to get the HITS function in R tool?

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I want to know how to find HITS function in R. Here is my code:

```
library(igraph)
library(proxy)

 A <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
             nrow=6, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)

 G <- graph.adjacency(A, mode=c("directed"), weighted=NULL)

 kmax <- 6

 op <- HITS(G,kmax)
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

> `Error in t.default(adj) : argument is not a matrix`

I coded the `HITS` function mentioned above, and I don't know how to implement it in a loop function for a large matrix.

```
HITS<-function(g,k)
  { 
    adj <- get.adjacency(g) 
    nodes <- dim(adj)[1] 
    auth <- c(rep(1,nodes)) 
    hub <- c(rep(1,nodes)) 
    for(i in 1:k){ 
        t_adj <- t(adj) 
        auth <- t_adj%*%hub 
        hub <- adj%*%auth 
        sum_sq_auth <- sum(auth*auth) 
        sum_sq_hub <- sum(hub*hub) 
        auth <- auth/sqrt(sum_sq_auth) 
        hub <- hub/sqrt(sum_sq_hub) 
    } 
    result <- c(auth,hub)   
    return(result) 
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://igraph.org/r/doc/kleinberg.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the `sparsematrices` option `TRUE`. Explicitly set it to `sparse=FALSE` while calling `get.adjacency` to get a full matrix instead of a sparse matrix.

```
> t(get.adjacency(G, sparse=F))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    1    0    1    1    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    1    0    1    0    0
[6,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

Otherwise, if you intend to work with large graphs and sparse matrices, install and load the `Matrix` library, [as recommended in the docs](http://igraph.org/r/doc/conversion.html).

```
> library(Matrix)
> t(get.adjacency(G))
6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . 1 . . . .
[2,] 1 . 1 . 1 .
[3,] 1 1 . 1 1 1
[4,] . 1 . . . .
[5,] . 1 . 1 . .
[6,] . 1 . . . .
```

---

After loading the `Matrix` package, the `HITS` algorithm works as is:

```
> HITS(G, 6)
[[1]]
6 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
          [,1]
[1,] 0.2378004
[2,] 0.3204131
[3,] 0.7613633
[4,] 0.2378004
[5,] 0.3847263
[6,] 0.2378004

[[2]]
6 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
          [,1]
[1,] 0.3874860
[2,] 0.6660588
[3,] 0.1147701
[4,] 0.4105226
[5,] 0.3874860
[6,] 0.2727159
```